Display Object values from an API object
I'm trying to create a Currency Conversion using an API, but I'm struggling finding out how to match the currency with it's value.
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="currency-from">
                <input type="number" id="main-currency">
                <select onchange="changeCurrency()" id="mainCurrency">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="currency-to">
                <input type="number">
                <select id="otherCurrency">
                    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="number" name="" id="" disabled>
</div>

const mainCurrency = document.getElementById('mainCurrency');
const inputCurrency = document.getElementById('main-currency');

function changeCurrency() {

    fetch(`https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD`)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(currency => {


        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(currency.rates)) {
            const currencyName = document.createElement('option');
            currencyName.innerHTML = key;
            currencyName.text = key;
            mainCurrency.appendChild(currencyName);
            inputCurrency.value = value;
          }
    })
}

changeCurrency()

It's always giving me the last value of the object.

Your HTML doesn't have IDs mainCurrency or main-currency.

Shouldn't inputCurrency.value = value be currencyName.value = value? Each option should have its value be the appropriate exchange rate, and you use that when the user selects one of the options.

You don't need to assign both .innerHTML and .text. They're the same thing for option.

Why are you calling changeCurrency() again when the user selects an option from the menu?

Because if I don't call changeCurrency() even though I'm using onchange on my html it doesn't do anything, the field remains blanks.

You need to call something when the user selects from the menu, but it shouldn't be changeCurrency().

You want to call a function that does inputCurrency.value = currencyName.value.

Your code is simply overwriting inputCurrency.value each time through the loop. So of course it has the last value when it's done. What value should it have instead?

One way is to keep the data in memory as a variable. Then get the matching value for a specific currency by looking up the key.
Demo: jsfiddle
const mainCurrency = document.getElementById('mainCurrency');
const inputCurrency = document.getElementById('main-currency');
var rates = []

function loadCurrencies() {

    fetch(`https://open.er-api.com/v6/latest/USD`)
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(currency => {
        // store this 
        rates = currency.rates
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(currency.rates)) {
            const currencyName = document.createElement('option');
            currencyName.text = key;
            mainCurrency.appendChild(currencyName);
          }
    })
}

loadCurrencies()

function changeCurrency(select) {
  var key = select.value
  var value = rates[key]
  inputCurrency.value = value
}

